# How does the equilibrium temperature of heat source depend on flow rate?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, thermodynamics

The scenario I'm considering is a heat source in a closed system which is initially at some temperature $T_{initial}$ and is in equilibrium with its surroundings, being cooled by air (at room temperature $T_{room}$ at a flow of rate $f_{initial}$, through some tube of constant area $A$.  Suppose we wanted to cool to some temperature $T'$, if we increase the flow rate this should be achievable, since this will maintain a larger temperature difference between the source and the surroundings. How could I characterise the temperature of the component as a function of time and air flow? I've tried using Newton's law of cooling but I'm just going around in circles.

Comment: heat flow is flow rate times delta-t.  Increase the flow rate, the delta T is less.  HEat flow is constant

Comment: I think it depends on the environment around the tube. If the temperature is lower than the inside air, the increase in flow rate over the constant area will result in higher velocity that causing the inside air to lose heat at a faster rate. The reverse is true also.

Comment: I assuming temperature of the heater is larger than the air, a higher flow rate should mean a larger temperature difference and hence increase rate of cooling of the heater